# How to correctly configure the remember me option of Spring Security in a project that use LDAP for authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-ldap

I am pretty new in Spring MVC and I have some problem trying to understand how to implement the "remember me" function into my login page.

So I am working on a Spring project that use the **4.1.7.RELEASE** version of Spring. This web application use Spring Security and **LDAP** to handle the users login.

Into this project I have this login page named **login.jsp**, this one:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", -1);
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- link href="<c:url value="resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet"-->

<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />"
    rel="stylesheet">

<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/login.css" />" rel="stylesheet">

<title>Login Page</title>



</head>

<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <!-- div id="intestazione">
        <h1 align="center">WIFI e PNSD</h1>
    </div-->

    <div class="container">
        <section id="sezioneBenvenuto">
            <h1 id="benvenuto" >Benvenuto</h1>
        </section>

        <section id="sezioneLogo" >
            <img src="resources/img/logo2.png" id="logo">
        </section>
        <section id="sezioneLogin">
            <div id="login-box">

                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                    <div class="error">${error}</div>
                </c:if>

                <form class="form-horizontal" name='loginForm' action="<c:url value='/j_spring_security_check' />" method='POST'>
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;" >
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                        <input type='text' name='username' class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Nome Utente">
                        <br>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="margin: 0px;" >
                        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                        <input type='password' name='password' class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                        <br>
                    </div>

                    <!--  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button> -->
                    <input id="ricorda" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Accedi" style="color: #0F8BB0;" />

                    <br>

                    <div style="white-space: nowrap; padding-top: 35px;">
                        <a id="linkGestioneUtenza" class="pull-left" href="${linkGestioneUtenza}">Gestione utenza</a>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <input style="vertical-align: top;" type="checkbox">
                            <label style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: normal; color: #0F8BB0;">Ricordami</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!--jsp:include page="footer.jsp" /-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, as you can see in the previous code snippet, there is this checkbox that represent the **remember me** choice:

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <input style="vertical-align: top;" type="checkbox">
    <label style="vertical-align: top; font-weight: normal; color: #0F8BB0;">Ricordami</label>
</div>
```

Ok, using the previous **login.jsp** page I have no problem to access to access to my application using my credential but, if I check the remember me checkbox, it can't work (infact when I access again to the application I have to insert again my credential).

So I read the official documentation and I find that I have to implement or configure this behavior by sending a cookie to the browser, with the cookie being detected during future sessions and causing automated login to take place, as explained here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/remember-me.html

From what I can understand there are 2 ways to do it:

1. **The first one uses hashing to preserve the security of cookie-based tokens**.
2. **The second uses a database or other persistent storage mechanism to
   store the generated tokens**

And here the first doubts: what exactly means these assertions? What are the difference between these 2 approaches?

In the documentation I can also read:

> Note that both implemementations require a **UserDetailsService**. If
>   you are using an authentication provider which doesn’t use a
>   **UserDetailsService** (for example, the **LDAP** provider) then it won’t work unless you also have a **UserDetailsService** bean in your
>   **application context**.

Ok, in this project the user authentication is made using **LDAP**. Reading the documentation it seems to me that **UserDetailsService** is an interface (so have to be implemented by a custom concrete class?) which loads user-specific data.

So now my doubts are: what exatly does this **UserDetailsService** ? Where have I to declare it to have it into my **application context**? Into the Spring Security configuration file (**spring-security.xml**) or in the Spring configuration file (**root-context.xml**) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**what exactly means these assertions?**

Basically remember me functionality does 2 things

1. After successful login, it creates a "rememeber-me" browser cookie
   with a token based on username,password ( token can be computed and
   persisted in db if needed or it can be on the fly computed hash of
   user,password).
2. When the user tries to access the secured page without any session
   (session is expired because of timeout), then RememberMe service
   will try to autoLogin the user by reversing the process (get cookie
   and check with userDetails hash or check with persisted token in db
   )

**What are the difference between these 2 approaches?**

*TokenBasedRememberMeServices* -

1. It uses hashing of user details to preserve the security of
   cookie-based tokens.
2. It contains a hash of the password, this solution is potentially
   vulnerable if the cookie is captured.

PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices

1. It uses a database or other persistent storage mechanism to store
   the generated tokens.
2. It uses a unique series identifier for the user. This identifies the
   initial login of the user and remains constant each time the user
   gets logged in automatically during that persistent session. It also
   contains a random token that is regenerated each time a user logs in
   via the persisted remember-me functions. This combination of
   randomly generated series and token are persisted, making a brute
   force attack very unlikely.

**Example for your usecase**

```
public class LdapUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
//Basically you need user details , username,password,roles you can fetch from your LdapService

        final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        final SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        authorities.add(authority);

return new User(userName, "password", authorities);   }
```

Spring Security configuration file (spring-security.xml)

```
<!-- Remember me config -->
<security:http 
     <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
</security:http>
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com..LdapUserDetailsService"/>
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="myAppKey" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="myAppKey" />
  </bean>
  <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
     <security:authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"/>
  </security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: mmm...I have not understand if your example represent a solution that I can insert in my project. So I tryed to create the LdapUserDetailsService class into the service package of my project (copying and pasting the code that you have post to me). The problem is that on the GrantedAuthority object I obtain this error message: "GrantedAuthority cannot be resolved". Why?

Comment: mine is just an example..i haven't included any imports..if you have eclipse it can automatically import for you org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority

Answer (score 2):

UserDetailService is an interface which is used to load user specific data (for ex username and password etc). You will implement UserDetailService and then write your custom user detail service to provide user specific information.
Here is example of how you can use UserDetailService based authentication :-

[Custom UserDetailsService example for spring 3 security](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/)

And for remember me option you better go for cookie. It is not a good idea using database for remember me option. Just use cookie.